# array field sending values two times in rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have added a custom field to my form that needs to send an array of ids.

required result: `arr: => ["1","2","3"]`

current scenario: `arr: => ["1","2","3","1","2","3"]`

In my form (form is submitting through **ajax**):

```
 <% f.object.image_attachments.each do |img| %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :arr, value: img.id, multiple: true %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: How about check the array in a backend? In general, you can't trust data from params.

Comment: if you want an array to be submitted then the field should be named `arr[]`